# ReactNative: Text overflow over image

Tags: html, react-native, overflow

I m trying to get this result :

[image]

So far i achieved this one :

[image]

As you can see , the circle with text is not correctly displayed.

Here is my code :

```
<View style={{overflow:'visible'}}>
    <Image style={{flex:1, width:20, height:20, marginRight:20}} source={require('./assets/icon-caddy.png')}>
      <View style={{ flex:1, flexDirection:'row', backgroundColor:'#88b148', width: 15, height:15 , position:'absolute', left: 5, top:-5, backgroundColor:'#88b148', borderRadius:50, alignItems:'center', justifyContent:'center'}}>
        <Text style={{color:'#fff', fontSize:10 }}>0</Text>
      </View>
    </Image>
  </View>
```

The overflow attribute doesn not seem to do a lot , if i remove it the result remains the same.

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is the solution thanks to this code : https://rnplay.org/apps/rpv82A

```
<View style={{flex:1, height:40, width:40, justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center'}}>
          <Image style={{width:40}} source={require('./assets/icon-caddy.png')}/>
              <View style={{backgroundColor:'#88b148', borderRadius:50,position:'absolute',flex:1, justifyContent:'center',alignItems:'center', top: 0, left: 50}}>
                <Text style={{ color:'#fff', fontSize:8, margin:3 }}>20</Text>
              </View>
      </View>
```